# PHP multidimensional array being nested twice

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am using this function to get data from a database.

```
public function getModelSpecs($modelCode) {
    $modelSpecs = db::fetch_array("SELECT * FROM `product_specs` WHERE model='{$modelCode}'");

    return $modelSpecs;
}
```

And i am accessing by using a for loop based on the count of a previous item.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($model); $i++) {
    $modelSpecs[] = $product->getModelSpecs($model[$i]['code']);
    $count++;
}
echo "<pre>".print_r($modelSpecs, true)."</pre>";
```

This all works but why is it nesting my array like so, as in its two levels deep.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 183
                    [model] => ZS125-48A
                    [engine_brand] => 158FMI-B
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 172
                    [model] => STR125YB
                    [engine_brand] => K154FMI
                )

        )
```

Is that just the structure of it as i am already fetching array in the function or can i not make it so that it is only down one level like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
                [id] => 183
                [model] => ZS125-48A
                [engine_brand] => 158FMI-B
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
                [id] => 172
                [model] => STR125YB
                [engine_brand] => K154FMI
        )
```

Thanks

Comment: Your SQL fetch is returning a multidimensional array and then you are adding each element in the array to each element of a new array.

Comment: check by printing $modelSpecs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update everyone i have fixed the issue by using fetch_row so it fetches a new row each time then stores it into the array.

```
public function getModelSpecs($modelCode) {
    $modelSpecs = db::fetch_row("SELECT * FROM `product_specs` WHERE model='{$modelCode}'");

    return $modelSpecs;
}
```

Comment: You answered your own question. A good example of 'Rubber ducking'. ;)  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: You also removed the `[]`, which I think may have been your problem.

Answer (score 6):

I think the line

```
$modelSpecs[] = $product->getModelSpecs($model[$i]['code']);
```

should just be

```
$modelSpecs = $product->getModelSpecs($model[$i]['code']);
```

Otherwise you are assigning your result set to an element of the $modelSpecs array, whereas I think you are trying to assign $modelSpecs to the whole of the result set.

Answer (score -1):

fetch_array returns an array of entries.

so it's like

- [0] = entry 1
- [1] = entry 2
- ...etc

So if you only want the first entry you need to do a reset() on it to get the first item. Here is the updated code that should work...

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($model); $i++) {
    $modelSpecs[] = reset($product->getModelSpecs($model[$i]['code']));
    $count++;
}
echo "<pre>".print_r($modelSpecs, true)."</pre>";
```

This will cause an error if that function for some reason doesn't return an array (if the query finds nothing so you might want to do this instead.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($model); $i++) {
    $myModelSpec=$product->getModelSpecs($model[$i]['code']);
    //goes to the next item if this last item isn't an array.
    if(!is_array($myModelSpec)) continue;
    $modelSpecs[] = reset($myModelSpec);
    $count++;
}
echo "<pre>".print_r($modelSpecs, true)."</pre>";
```